# how to get the registration id for C2DM server of google for push notification?

Tags: android

For push notification i'm planning to use C2DM google server but to use it registraion ID is need.I tried alot to get the registration id but unable to get registration id if anyone have succeded to get it then please assist me to get it

thank you in advance.

Comment: i can't get u..make the question clearly

Comment: for getting registration id you should put your all ur permission at proper place plz check ur manifiest file again..

Comment: **`i hope this link help u ..`**

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9033213/how-to-retrive-registration-id-and-send-massage-to-third-party-application-in-an/9080754#9080754

Answer (score 0):

Registration ID is sent by the Android mobile which has atleast version 2.2 and is connected to a google account. This registration ID is inturn used by your third party server to send the payload to the c2dm server which pushes it to the mobile

Before you get registration ID you need to get the Authorization ID from the c2dm server which can be obtained by a simple browser request like this one

https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin?accountType=GOOGLE&Email=xxx@gmail.com&Passwd=xxx&source=Google&service=ac2dm