# cloud computing in android

Tags: android, google-app-engine, cloud, data-synchronization

i am trying to build an android application in relation to cloud computing. 
it aims in creating a multiple user,data synchronizing application using Google app engine.
users have previlege to log-in and share documents hosted in cloud,among selected users and provides provision for each user to edit those documents which would be notified among the group.
i am beginner in this field.
please provide some tips and guidance.
any hints or sample codes would be greatly appreciated.

thanks in advance..

Comment: This is not really the place to be asking this. You should google around for some basic tutorials on AppEngine and Android first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is not clear. What to you don't. If you have know that

1. how to retrieve Registration id and send massage to third-party
   application in android c2dm. Then you use this link for Android cloud
   computing.

   [how to retrive Registration id and send message to third-party application in android c2dm0+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9033213/how-to-retrive-registration-id-and-send-massage-to-third-party-application-in-an/9080754#9080754)
2. if you take any idea for C2dm Android, then use this link.

   http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/

Hope this helps you along!